# -I and -L and -l are all correct, but I still get a linker error

Tags: c++, linker

```
gcc test.cpp -I/CORRECT_DIRECTORY_FOR_HEADERS -L/CORRECT_DIRECTORY_FOR_LIBRARIES -llibshogun (name is libshogun.dylib)
```

I get

> ld: library not found for -llibshogun clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

No idea why. Any help would be much appreciated.

I've tried setting the `-rpath` like such:`-Wl,-rpath,/CORRECT_DIRECTORY_FOR_LIBRARIES`

That also does not change the error.

The library absolutely exists. I can see it quite clearly in my finder. I am on OSX.

Thank you to anyone that helps!

Comment: _"-I and -L and -l are all correct"_ Nope, they're not. Someone forgot to read the documentation for the `-l` switch. That someone... was you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-lshogun` without `lib` prefix.

Comment: And that totally solved it. I must have been staring at the documentation for 2 hours and just totally read completely over it. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped to solve your problem, please consider marking it as accepted.